# validate files in laravel using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5, vue2-dropzone

I'm trying to upload files and validate files in laravel and vue.js that uses dropzone/vue library, the file has various mimetypes such as doc, docx,  xls, xlsx,  ppt, jpg, jpeg, ptx, gif, png, txt, Here is my code snippet for laravel. The code seems to look good but still I couldnot validate jpg and jpeg mime types. and I would like to know how to pass the error to the vue component

```
public function postFileUpload(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
            ['file' => 'required|mimes:png,gif,pdf,jpg,jpeg,txt|max:8192']
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            echo 'in';
            exit();
//            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
//            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->withError('please select file type');
        } else {

            echo 'out';
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using vee-validate instead: http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/validation.html#rule-ext to validate the file on the client-side

v-validate.reject="'required|ext:png,gif,pdf,jpg,jpeg,txt|size:8192'"